# Dynamically call method of a class with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I want to dynamically call the method of a custom class much like the below javascript. Except, the javascript below only calls a function that exists in my code. I want to call (dynamically) the function of a class. So I would remove `window{value](target, event, self);` and use something else that would call the method of a custom created class such as "mycustomclass.anythingcouldbethismethod(target, event, self);" after it had been instantiated of course.

```
var functions = [
                 'ajaxify_overlay',
                 'ajaxify_overlayCancel',
                 'ajaxify_overlaySubmit',
                 'ajaxify_rollout',
                 'ajaxify_rolloutCancel',
                 'ajaxify_rolloutSubmit',
                 'ajaxify_upload',
                 'ajaxify_contentArea',
                 'ajaxify_itemToggler',
                 'ajaxify_closer',
                 'ajaxify_submit',
                 'ajaxify_inputActivate',
                 'ajaxify_executeAndRefresh',
                 'ajaxify_empty' 
               ];

$(document).bind('ready', function(event) {   

  $('body').live('click', function (event){   

   var target = $(event.target);

   var self = this;  

   $.each(functions, function(index, value){

     if($(target).hasClass(value)) {

       window[value](target, event, self);

     }

          });    

       });

});
```

Comment: What is it that you're asking?

Comment: @Jakub: so you just instantiated a class. You want to call a method of that class. The name of the method is stored in some variable as a string. How do you call the method? (this is vastly simplifying the above)

Comment: he simply wants to call the methods dynamically which are kept in the array named `functions`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var myClass = { /* your class definition */ };
var methodName = 'myMethod';
myClass[methodName](p1,p2,...,pN);
```

Comment: Would this work if i did var myClass = new CustomClass(); where CustomClass is a class i created?

Comment: great this does work, thank you i didn't realize i could use bracket and dot notation with JS classes.

Comment: @bmarti44 This works for all JavaScript objects.  For example, you could do: var arr = []; var methodName = 'push'; arr[methodName](1);

Comment: either way is fine, i picked brackets for brevity. there's no difference in the method call.

Comment: Everything that is not a primitive in JS is an object so you are free to play with its properties using both dot and bracket notation.

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
function methodCaller( methodName, target, event, self ) {
    mycustomclass[ methodName ](target, event, self);
}

methodCaller( "someMethodName" );
```